Сворачивающийся заголовок при скроле
Я пытаюсь сделать плавно сворачивающийся при скроле заголовок.
У меня есть код с JavaScript:


var hp   = document.body.scrollHeight,
    hw   = window.innerHeight,
    smax = hp - hw,
    smin = 0,
    hmin = 25,
    hmax = 75,
    ds   = smax - smin,
    dh   = hmax - hmin;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var s = window.pageYOffset; // current scrollTop
    var h = hmax - (dh * s) / ds;

    actionbar.style.height = h + 'px';
});
#actionbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: #333e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}
<div id="actionbar">Action Bar</div>
<div>С другой стороны постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании форм развития.
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании форм развития. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. Разнообразный и богатый опыт начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Равным образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что сложившаяся структура организации позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании соответствующий условий активизации. Равным образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности требуют от нас анализа существенных финансовых и административных условий. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации соответствующий условий активизации. Не следует, однако забывать, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание дальнейших направлений развития.
Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм развития. Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений.
Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет важную роль в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа направлений прогрессивного развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Разнообразный и богатый опыт начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции способствует подготовки и реализации соответствующий условий активизации</div>



Но проблема в том что таким образом он сворачивается до нужного размера только когда я пролистаю всю страницу. Мне нужно чтобы это происходило через несколько пикселей прокрутки.
Как это можно реализовать?

Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

@ΝNL993 вставил фрагмент кода

Vladislav G. в своём ответе подтолкнул меня на правильный путь (использовать if). Но таким образом как он написал при быстром скроле со смартфона заголовок может свернуться не полностью. Я нашёл этому решение! Надо всего лишь вместо:
if (h <= hmin) return;
actionbar.style.height = h + 'px';

написать:
if (h <= hmin) {
 actionbar.style.height = hmin + 'px';
}else {
 actionbar.style.height = h + 'px';
}

Вот и всё. Решение было под носом!

Возможно это то, что тебе нужно. Вместо 250 можно поставить другое число. Чем оно больше, тем быстрее будет сворачиватсья заголовок.


var hp   = document.body.scrollHeight,
    hw   = window.innerHeight,
    smax = hp - hw,
    smin = 0,
    hmin = 25,
    hmax = 75,
    ds   = smax - smin - 250,
    dh   = hmax - hmin;

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    var s = window.pageYOffset; // current scrollTop
    var h = hmax - (dh * s) / ds;
    if (h <= hmin) return;

    actionbar.style.height = h + 'px';
});
#actionbar {
  position: fixed;
  background: #333e;
  width: 100%;
  height: 75px;
}
<div id="actionbar">Action Bar</div>
<div>С другой стороны постоянный количественный рост и сфера нашей активности представляет собой интересный эксперимент проверки направлений прогрессивного развития. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также сложившаяся структура организации позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Товарищи! укрепление и развитие структуры обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании форм развития.
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что рамки и место обучения кадров обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании форм развития. Задача организации, в особенности же новая модель организационной деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации системы обучения кадров, соо
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>тветствует насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий влечет за собой процесс внедрения и модернизации систем массового участия. Разнообразный и богатый опыт начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции позволяет оценить значение направлений прогрессивного развития. Равным образом рамки и место обучения кадров позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям. Задача организации, в особенности же реализация намеченных плановых заданий позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке системы обучения кадров, соответствует насущным потребностям.
Значимость этих проблем настолько очевидна, что сложившаяся структура организации позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании соответствующий условий активизации. Равным образом дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности требуют от нас анализа существенных финансовых и административных условий. Таким образом начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании систем массового участия. Идейные соображения высшего порядка, а также постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности способствует подготовки и реализации соответствующий условий активизации. Не следует, однако забывать, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий в значительной степени обуславливает создание дальнейших направлений развития.
Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности позволяет выполнять важные задания по разработке форм развития. Равным образом постоянное информационно-пропагандистское обеспечение нашей деятельности обеспечивает широкому кругу (специалистов) участие в формировании новых предложений.
Товарищи! дальнейшее развитие различных форм деятельности играет важную роль в формировании существенных финансовых и административных условий. Равным образом рамки и место обучения кадров требуют от нас анализа направлений прогрессивного развития. Не следует, однако забывать, что реализация намеченных плановых заданий позволяет оценить значение позиций, занимаемых участниками в отношении поставленных задач. Разнообразный и богатый опыт начало повседневной работы по формированию позиции способствует подготовки и реализации соответствующий условий активизации</div>




Да, спасибо! Это то что мне нужно. Но к сожалению при очень быстрой прокрутке (на смартфоне) заголовок сворачивается неполностью... Пример: https://codepen.io/AndrewSorocka/pen/abgLmme

Я нашёл как исправить то что я описал выше в комментарии. Т. к. это полностью мне подходит я оформлю это в виде ответа на свой же вопрос.
